# How to get random sampling by fixed size in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I set following sql, it returned errors

`select is not at valid at this position ・・・`

```
set @size = 10;

select * from table order by rand() limit @size;
```

What is wrong with this code ?

or are there any way to achieve this ?

`select version()` returned `5.6.10`

I would like to get random sampling in fixed size.

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Comment: LIMIT cannot be a user variable. Which MySQL version?

Comment: LIMIT operand(s) may be parametrized only while using dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Comment: You can create a prepared statement or if using MariaDB-10.2+ an [execute immediate concat('select * from table order by rand() limit ', @size)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/)

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL is probably the way to go.  However, you could enumerate the rows and then use `<=`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum
      from (select t.* from t order by rand()) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
where seqnum <= @size;
```

In more modern versions of MySQL, this is a bit simpler:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= @size;
```

Or even using the overloaded `having` clause:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by rand()) as seqnum
from t
having seqnum <= @size;
```